# initializing 2d array of a struct

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, constructor, struct

normally initialization of member variable of struct would take place inside its constructor

```
struct line
{
  line()
  {
     length=0;
     name[0] = '\0';
  }
  int length;
  char name[10];
};
```

but how would i initialize 2d array to 0 or null values?

```
struct myValues
{
  myValues()
  {
    my2dDimension[0][0] = { 0 }; //shows error:expected an expression
  }
  int my2dDimension[20][2];
}
```

if i don't initialize them they'll contain garbage values, which i don't want.

Comment: The error is telling you that you have defined `my2dDimension` to be an `int`, not a 2D array.

Comment: you declare my2dDimension as int not 2D array.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention `my2dDimension[20][2];`

Comment: Prefer std::vector< std::vector<int> > unless you have a good reason for using a raw array. It will initialize itself.

Answer (score 3):

I would use memset

```
struct myValues
{
  myValues()
  {
    memset(my2dDimension, 0, sizeof my2dDimension);
  }
  int my2dDimension[20][2];
}
```

memset fills a block of memory with a given value (zero in this case) to a given size in bytes.

Comment: It can be any byte value. NULL is generally used for pointers, so I wouldn't recommend using it for memset.

Comment: @David the thing is if that `my2dDimension` contains points of a graph then u don't want them to be 0, the graphs last point would always be [0,0], however if i do `NULL` then i will not face that problem i guess, sorry if i'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

> how would i initialize 2d array to 0 or null values?

Bellow is initialization to 0 for plain structures:

```
struct SomeStruct{};
SomeStruct someStruct;
::memset ( &someStruct, 0, sizeof(SomeStruct) );
```

For more advanced types of initializations you can look at [C++11 initializer lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Initializer_lists) and [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html)